# How to open an external link from homescreen widget's listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-widget

I have a homescreen widget which is populated with data in a listview. Each row is associated with a link, and on click of an item, I want to open the associated url.

I have everything set up except the onclicklistener for each item. I've come across similar questions, but they all are in regards to opening an activity, whereas I want to open an external link.

Here's my onUpdate() from class extending AppWidgetProvider:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int[] appWidgetIDs) {

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIDs.length; i++) {
        final RemoteViews remoteViews;
        final int id = appWidgetIDs[i];
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                        context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
       remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list,
                        getIntent(context, id));
       updateWidget(appWidgetManager, id, remoteViews);

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIDs);
}
```

and here's my getViewAt() from RemoteViewsFactory:

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    row = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_row);
    final ModelClass modelClass = AppWidget.filteredList.get(position);
    row.setTextViewText(R.id.title, modelClass.getTitle());
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use web-view, on each item click instantiate a web-view. I would go with this library it is really beautiful.
https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android

Comment: How do I parcel the URL with the intent, and how do I retrieve the URL I my AppWidgetProvider?

Comment: you know i cant answer that without seeing the structure of what you are describing sir.

Comment: Updated the question.